# How do I update the avatar picture in real time without submit button

Tags: javascript, php, mysql

I want to update the avatar picture of my app automatically after selecting the picture from the system's local directory.

Like if you select your profile picture from let's say Facebook for example, it updates automatically without having to click another submit button.
I am writing my app in PHP and JavaScript but mainly PHP.
This is my code for the avatar update function.

```
$msg = "";
  $msg_class = "";
  $conn = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "micro");
  if (isset($_POST['save_profile'])) {
    // for the database
    $bio = stripslashes($_POST['bio']);
    $profileImageName = './propics/avatar.jpg';
    // For image upload
    $target_dir = "propics/";
    $target_file = $target_dir . basename($profileImageName);
    // VALIDATION
    // validate image size. Size is calculated in Bytes
    if($_FILES['profileImage']['size'] > 200000) {
      $msg = "Image size should not be greated than 200Kb";
      $msg_class = "alert-danger";
    }
    // check if file exists
    if(file_exists($target_file)) {
      $msg = "File already exists";
      $msg_class = "alert-danger";
    }
    // Upload image only if no errors
    if (empty($error)) {
      if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES["profileImage"]["tmp_name"], $target_file)) {
        $sql = "UPDATE users SET propic='$profileImageName' WHERE uname='admin'";
//$sql = "INSERT INTO users SET propic='$profileImageName'";
        if(mysqli_query($conn, $sql)){
          $msg = "Image uploaded and saved in the Database";
          $msg_class = "alert-success";
        } else {
          $msg = "There was an error in the database";
          $msg_class = "alert-danger";
        }
      } else {
        $error = "There was an erro uploading the file";
        $msg = "alert-danger";
      }
    }
  }
```

Below is my html input code

```
 <div class="col-4 offset-md-4 " style="margin-top: -50px">                    

                      <?php if (!empty($msg)): ?>
                        <div class="alert <?php echo $msg_class ?>" role="alert">
                          <?php echo $msg; ?>
                        </div>
                      <?php endif; ?>
                      <div class="form-group text-center" style="position: relative;" >
                        <span class="img-div">
                          <div class="text-center img-placeholder"  onClick="triggerClick()">
                            <h4>Update image</h4>
                          </div>
                          <img src="propics/avatar.jpg" onClick="triggerClick()" id="profileDisplay" style="width: 128px;height: 128px;">
                        </span>
                        <input type="file" name="profileImage" onChange="displayImage(this)" id="profileImage" class="form-control" style="display: none;">

                      </div>                      

                  </div>
```

Comment: That’s why AJAX have been created, search JQuery and AJAX on Google

Comment: PS: a good tutorial —> https://www.w3schools.com/xml/ajax_intro.asp

Answer (score 0):

You have to use Ajax to save your avatar image without loading page or you can say live upload. Follow the below code example. You can also check on internet you will find many example.

```
$('#inputFile').change(function(){
  startUpload();
});

function startUpload(){

$.ajax({
url: "ajax_php_file.php", // Url to which the request is send
type: "POST",             // Type of request to be send, called as method
data: new FormData(this), // Data sent to server, a set of key/value pairs (i.e. form fields and values)
contentType: false,       // The content type used when sending data to the server.
cache: false,             // To unable request pages to be cached
processData:false,        // To send DOMDocument or non processed data file it is set to false
success: function(data)   // A function to be called if request succeeds
{
$('#loading').hide();
$("#message").html(data);
}
});
```

ajax_php_file.php

```
$sourcePath = $_FILES['file']['tmp_name'];       // Storing source path of the file in a variable
$targetPath = "upload/".$_FILES['file']['name']; // Target path where file is to be stored
move_uploaded_file($sourcePath,$targetPath) ;    // Moving Uploaded file
return "successfully uploaded";
```

Comment: Can you explain the #inputFile line, where do i implement that code in a separate php file or same file?

Comment: in the same file where your <input type="file" id="inputFile" name="file"> added.

Comment: i dont see the database insert query how does this code update to the database?

Comment: You need to add the file name in the database using MYSQL QUERY.